# Is it possible to edit the backend of TYPO3?

Tags: php, typo3

I'm trying to understand TYPO3 a little bit better and I really want to be able to work with the full potential of TYPO3. So here is what I'm trying to do:

On my Website I have a navigation with little Icons next to the actual page name. I used the *Resources* tab in the backend to select and upload a file which will be used as the image next to my page name.

Now here is where it gets tricky. I also want to be able to set an image which will be used as a header image on the page. I know I can do stuff like use the first image for this purpose and the second image for another one but I thought maybe there is a pretty way of doing this by adding another media input next to the one that already exists. I know I might have to get through some php stuff but I'm willing to learn if there actually is a way. Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to do:

[image: What I'm trying to do]

Does anyone know if this is possible and can link me some tutorials or tell it right away? I've tried to google it but I didn't find anything that looked clear to me and since I'm not to familiar with PHP I don't want to mess around and randomly try some scripts..

Comment: added to georg's tutorial you might want to have a look at https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/pagelist/ , which uses this implementation of an additional image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is of course possible, there are a couple of tutorials how to extend the pages table with an additional field, e.g. https://www.sebkln.de/en/tutorials/detail/how-to-extend-typo3-database-tables-with-new-fields/